# How can I remove a character from a string while doing character by character processing?

Tags: f#

I'm fairly new to F# but I'm struggling to find how to properly represent the null character in the language. **Can anyone tell me how to represent the null character in F#?**

More to the point, what started me down the path is I'm trying to do some string processing with `String.mapi`, but I can't figure out how to remove a character in the below function:

```
let GetTargetFrameworkFolder version =
    let versionMapper i c =
        match c with
        | 'v' -> if i = 0 then char(0x000) else c
        | '.' -> char(0x000)
        | _ -> c

    match version with
        | "v3.5" -> "net35"
        | "v4.0" -> "net40"        
        | "v4.5" -> "net45"  
        | vers -> vers |> String.mapi versionMapper

GetTargetFrameworkFolder "v4.5.1" |> Dump
```

How can I remove a character from a string while doing character by character processing, as in the case with `String.map` and `String.mapi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove a character using `String.mapi`, as this function maps exactly one character from the input to one character from the output. The null character is not the same thing as removing a character; it's just another character that happens to have the code 0.

In your case, if I understand correctly you want to remove the initial 'v' (if any) and remove dots. I would do it like this:

```
let GetTargetFrameworkFolder version =
    match version with
    | "v3.5" -> "net35"
    | "v4.0" -> "net40"        
    | "v4.5" -> "net45"
    | vers ->
        let vers = if vers.[0] = 'v' then vers.[1..] else vers
        vers.Replace(".", "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the 1 to 1 mapping

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this if you wanted to keep your original approach would be to write your own choose function for strings:

```
module String =

    let choosei predicate str =
        let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()

        let choose i (c:char) = 
            match predicate i c with
                | Some(x) -> sb.Append(c) |> ignore
                | None -> ()

        str |> String.iteri choose 

        sb.ToString()
```

Then use it as follows:

```
let GetTargetFrameworkFolder version =
    let versionMapper i = function
        | 'v' when i = 0 -> None
        | '.' -> None
        | c -> Some(c)

    match version with
        | "v3.5" -> "net35"
        | "v4.0" -> "net40"        
        | "v4.5" -> "net45"  
        | vers -> vers |> String.choosei versionMapper

GetTargetFrameworkFolder "v4.5.1" |> Dump
```

Comment: I really like this approach as it doesn't require me to enumerate the string twice which is what essentially happens with `string.Replace`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using an array comprehension:

```
let GetTargetFrameworkFolder version =
    match version with
    | "v3.5" -> "net35"
    | "v4.0" -> "net40"        
    | "v4.5" -> "net45"  
    | vers -> new String([|
        for i in 0 .. vers.Length - 1 do
            match i, vers.[i] with
            | 0, 'v' | _, '.' -> () // skip 'v' at [0] and all '.'s
            | _, c -> yield c // let everything else through
    |])
```

Comment: +1 For showing the usage of yield... was wondering if F# had an equivalent of C#'s yield

Comment: @Damian, you're welcome. In fact, F#'s `yield` is a far more general and powerful thing that C#'s. Read up on [computation expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

By character processing while removing a character is filtering (`string` is a sequence of `char`):

```
let version (s: String) =
    s
    |> Seq.filter (fun ch -> ch <> '.' && ch <> 'v')
    |> String.Concat
```

**UPDATE:**

To skip first 'v':

```
let version (s: String) =
    s
    |> Seq.skip (if s.StartsWith "v" then 1 else 0)
    |> Seq.filter ((<>) '.')
    |> String.Concat
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for as this removes all the vs.

Comment: @Damian then just skip first 'v':
`let version (s: String) = s |> Seq.skip (if s.StartsWith "v" then 1 else 0) |> Seq.filter ((<>) '.') |> String.Concat`
or just use a RegEx.